# Unable to retrieve, modify an image element within a form

Tags: javascript, image, dom

I'm having some trouble changing an image being displayed on a page by way of a dropdown menu (`select` element) selection.

Getting the dropdown menu to give me an alert when I make a selection works fine:

```
function imageSelect()
{
  var index = document.getElementById("myForm").availableImages.selectedIndex;  
  var value = document.getElementById("myForm").availableImages.options[index].value;
    
  alert("test " + value); // alert box pops up upon list item selection
}
```

Even though the `select` element is embedded within a division, paragraph, and label tag, it still works. ("availableImages" is the name of this element)

However, within the same function I am having an issue with changing the source of my image tag... Any ideas?

#### Relevant markup

```
<label id = "pics">
  <br />
  <img name = "pic"src = "museum.jpg" alt = "Temp Image"/> <!-- place holder image-->
  <br />
</label>
```

My attempt to change the src in the same JavaScript function:

```
document.getElementById["myForm"].getElementById["centreDiv"].getElementById["pics"].pic.src = "wolves.jpg";
```

This is a no go.

---

#### Conclusion

Perfect, Adarshr. Thank you for your help! I have a sneaking suspicion that my square brackets were the main cause of my issue; none the less, I very much appreciate your help!

Comment: Could you post a bit more of your code, and how you are trying to assign the image?

Comment: It'd help if you posted the code for the image, as well as the code you're trying to use to set the image.  Working code is all well and good, but it's easier to find the problem if you show us the part that's broken

Comment: What is the issue?  Is there an error in the JS console?  Does anything on the page change?

Comment: I posted a bit more code. The image remains unchanged when I make a list selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just doing this should help

```
<img name="pic" id="picId" src="museum.jpg" alt="Temp Image"/> <!-- place holder image-->
```

and in JS,

```
document.getElementById('picId').src = 'wolves.jpg';
```